# How to make accordion in angular2 to work as Collapsible Panel

Tags: angular

I have an accordion, in that accordion i need to make animation in Collapsible Panel format, Please can any one help me to do this type of animation in my accordion of angular2.

i am here by sharing my HTML code:
I have an accordion, in that accordion i need to make animation in this format,

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_panel&stacked=h

Please can any one help me to do this type of animation in my accordion:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="today col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div *ngFor="let group of groups">
    <accordion>
    <accordion-group #groupUser class="outer admin access">
    <div accordion-heading>
    {{group.group.groupName}}
   <i class="pull-right" [ngClass]="{'closeArrowGray': groupUser?.isOpen, 'openArrowGray': !groupUser?.isOpen}"></i>
  </div>
 <div>
 <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead style="color:#00bcd4;font-size:20.24px;">
  <tr>
  <th class="page">Page</th>
  <th class="view">View</th>
  <th class="permision">Permission</th>
  </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody class="table_body accssBody" style="font-size: 15px;">
   <tr *ngFor="let page of group.pages">
   <td class="accessLabel">
   {{page.viewName}}
   </td>
   <td>
   <md-slide-toggle  style="width: 40px;margin: 0 auto;"></md-slide-toggle>
    </td>
  <td>
 <md-slide-toggle *ngIf='page.view_permission == true'></md-slide-toggle>
</td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
     </table>
      </div>
       </accordion-group>
       </accordion>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```